# z-index a single div inside another one

Tags: html, css, z-index

The title might be a little bit misleading, but I didn't knew how to phrase my problem correctly...
So here it is :

```css
.header {
 height:1000px;
 width:400px;
 background-color:red;
 z-index:0;
    color:blue;
}
.text {
    position:fixed;
}
.page {
 height:1000px;
 width:400px;
 padding:20px;
 background-color:black;
 z-index:0;
}

.container {
 height:150px;
 width:350px;
 background-color:white;
 z-index:20;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><span class=text>Hello</span></div>

<div class="page ">
 <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

So what I'd like to do here, is simple have the "Hello" text OVER the red and the black divs, as it is already, but UNDER the white div... It's simply a matter of z-indexes I think, but I can't figure out a way to do it...

Comment: z-index does nothing on statically positioned elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Just add `position:relative` property to `.container` div :)